# 2 WP_Querys repeating one after the other - Styled Differently

Tags: php, themes, wordpress

I'm trying to get 2 different styled posts to show up one after the other and then back around. So it should look like
DB 
Uncategorized 
DB 
Uncategorized 
etc

And to have them both styled differently. I'm not great with PHP and the best I got so far was all in one category and then all in the other.

```
<section class="home-middle">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">

  <?php
   $args = array('category_name' => 'designer backstage',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => '3' );
    $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

  if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
  while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
     $category_posts->the_post();
?>       
          <div class="stylists-book">
                <div class="image">
                  <div class="meta-designer">
                        <div class="pro-pic"><img src="images/stylists-pro1.jpg"></div>
                        <h3>Designer<hr></h3>
                        <p><a href="#"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>
                        <span><?php the_date(); ?></span>
                  </div>
                    <img><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>

           <?php

   $args = array('category_name' => 'uncategorized',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => '3');
   $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

   if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
  while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
     $category_posts->the_post();
 ?>  

 <div class="look" style="max-height: 200px">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="team-modster">
                          <span><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </div>
               </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
       <img style="height:200px" src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" />
       </a>
     </div>
              </div>
                </div>
                     <?php endwhile; else: >

  Oops, there are no posts.

 <?php endif; ?>

          </div> 

         </div>
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>           

    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker took a look at it and got it working. Figured I would post the solution.

```
<?php

$args = array('category_name' => 'designer-backstage',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '5' );
 $designer_posts = new WP_Query($args);

 $args = array('category_name' => 'uncategorized',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '5' );
 $uncategorized_posts = new WP_Query($args);

 if ($designer_posts->have_posts() && $uncategorized_posts->have_posts()) :
// If a new category is added, add it to this array
$category_posts = [$designer_posts, $uncategorized_posts];
$cat_posts_idx = 0;

$new_category_posts = [];

$post_count = 0;
$max_posts = 10;

// Alternate categories and store into a new posts array
while ($post_count < $max_posts) {
    // Iterate the post
    $category_posts[$cat_posts_idx]->the_post();

    // get_the_category() returns an array with one item in this case
    $category = get_the_category()[0];

    if ($category->slug == 'designer-backstage') { ?>

        <div class="stylists-book">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="meta-designer">
                    <div class="pro-pic"><img src="images/stylists-pro1.jpg"></div>
                        <h3>Designer<hr></h3>
                        <p><a href="#"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>
                        <span><?php the_date(); ?></span>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div>


    <?php }
    else if ($category->slug == 'uncategorized') { ?>

        <div class="look">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="team-m">
                        <span><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8" style="max-height: 225px; overflow: hidden;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img style="" src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" /></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>

    <?php }



else:
 ?>
Oops, there are no posts.
<?php
endif;
?>
```